# when copying table from AzureDataLakeStore to ASQLServer string fields appear between double quotes in ASQLServer

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-sql-server

I have a table in AzureDataLake, and a table defined in AzureSQLServer. 
One of the activities in the pipeline copies form one to the other. 
However, for some reason string fields appear between double quotes 
[screenshot of what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUmR0.png)

the table looks fine when I do a preview in DataLakseStoreAnalytics, where it's also replicated [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYo3Y.png)

any clue of what is going on? 
It might be something quite basic, but just got started with Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your source file format? Does it have " ?
In  your input dataset, in the format section, you could try to add

```
"typeProperties": {
        "format": {
            "quoteChar": "\""
        }
```

}

Comment: Yes indeed that was it